# How can I dump the output of the x command in gdb to a file?

Tags: binary, gdb

I am examining some binary data in gdb using something like `x 450bc` to look at 450 contiguous bytes of it. Is there a simple way to dump this output in raw binary form to a file in order to inquire about it with the sender through email?

I tried something like `dump binary filename x/450bc` but that didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like...

```
(gdb) p $pc
$1 = (void (*)()) 0x4004a7 <main+11>
(gdb) p $pc + 450
$2 = (void (*)()) 0x400669
(gdb) dump binary memory ./file $1 $2
```

Depends on the starting address.

Answer (score 2):

This is help for the command you are looking for:

```
(gdb) help dump binary memory
Write contents of memory to a raw binary file.
Arguments are FILE START STOP.  Writes the contents of memory
within the range [START .. STOP) to the specified FILE in binary format.
```

And this is an example how to use this command:

```
(gdb) dump binary memory my_binary_file.bin 0x22fd8a 0x22fd8a+450
```